# Jquery check if reached marker on a page when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I need to detect (in jquery) if a marker:

```
<div id="marker"></div>
```

has been reached/hit when scrolling down on a web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need this:

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/umifod/6/edit)**

```
function onScreen(){
  var markerPos = $('#marker').offset().top;
  var winScroll = $(document).scrollTop();
  var winH      = $(window).height();

  if( winScroll+winH >= markerPos){
    console.log('VISIBLE!');
  } 
}

$(window).on('scroll resize',function(){ 
    onScreen();  
});
```

Comment: @ShaneKm I realized that we should check also on **window resize**, so I modified my code to support that too

Answer (score 2):

Since you taged `jquery-plugins`, you may try a look at this plugin.

[jquery-appear](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-appear/)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try jQuery Waypoints plugin: http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/